# Need a optimized solution to get alphabetically ordered set of records javascript

Tags: javascript, json, performance, optimization

I have says more than 30K objects in an array:

```
var camp = [
       {
          "campaign_id":1,
          "name":"RE TW 155700375"
       },
       {
          "campaign_id":2,
          "name":"A_SC_TSTC_Q413_915495-172"
       },
       {
          "campaign_id":2,
          "name":"A_SC_TSTC_495-172"
       },
       {
          "campaign_id":4,
          "name":"R_413_915495-172"
       }
    ];
```

I want to get an object like :

```
{
   "A":[
      {
         "campaign_id":2,
         "name":"A_SC_TSTC_Q413_915495-172"
      },
      {
         "campaign_id":2,
         "name":"A_SC_TSTC_495-172"
      }
   ],
   "R":[
      {
         "campaign_id":4,
         "name":"R_413_915495-172"
      },
      {
         "campaign_id":1,
         "name":"RE TW 155700375"
      }
   ]
}
```

My effort so far : Able to get the json sorted,

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/88HVZ/15/)

```
function compareStrings(a, b) {
            // Assuming you want case-insensitive comparison
            a = a.toLowerCase();
            b = b.toLowerCase();
            return (a < b) ? -1 : (a > b) ? 1 : 0;
        }
camp.sort(function(a, b) {
    return compareStrings(a.name, b.name);
});
console.log('After SORT');
console.log(camp);
```

But I want an array like:

```
{
   "A":[
      {
         "campaign_id":2,
         "name":"A_SC_TSTC_Q413_915495-172"
      },
      {
         "campaign_id":2,
         "name":"A_SC_TSTC_495-172"
      }
   ],
   "R":[
      {
         "campaign_id":4,
         "name":"R_413_915495-172"
      },
      {
         "campaign_id":1,
         "name":"RE TW 155700375"
      }
   ]
}
```

I know I can use a for loop and check for each string first charecter and make it as a set. 
But remember I have 30K+ records, So iterating 30k records in a loop is performance issue.

So please suggest me a optimized solution for this.

Comment: Unless you operate on data, you cannot sort it, number of records doesn't matter.

Comment: If you were fine with *sorting* 30k items, then surely making a map by iterating them is not a performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

You probably can't get any more efficient than looping through the array at least once.

Maybe something like this will work?

We start off with your original data:

```
var camp = [
  {
    campaign_id: 1,
    name: "RE TW 155700375"
  },
  {
    campaign_id: 2,
    name: "A_SC_TSTC_Q413_915495-172"
  },
  {
    campaign_id: 2,
    name: "A_SC_TSTC_495-172"
  },
  {
    campaign_id: 4,
    name: "R_413_915495-172"
  }
];
```

First, we sort it alphabetically by "name":

```
camp.sort(function(a, b) {
  // Fetch the name for both objects
  a = a.name.toLowerCase();
  b = b.name.toLowerCase();

  // Objects are the same - return 0
  if (a === b) {
    return 0;
  }

  // Sort by name ascending (a > b)
  // To sort by descending, just replace the ">" with "<"
  return a > b ? 1 : -1;
});
```

Now your object looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    campaign_id: 2,
    name: "A_SC_TSTC_495-172"
  },
  {
    campaign_id: 2,
    name: "A_SC_TSTC_Q413_915495-172"
  },
  {
    campaign_id: 4,
    name: "R_413_915495-172"
  },
  {
    campaign_id: 1,
    name: "RE TW 155700375"
  }
]
```

Secondly, we do the actual grouping work - here I've added the grouping function as a prototype to the Array object, but feel free to adapt it to use just a normal function:

```
Array.prototype.groupAlphabeticallyByKey = function (key) {
  // Create a local grouped object
  var grouped = {};

  // Loop through each index of this array
  this.forEach(function (object) {
    // Grab the first character and capitalise it
    var firstChar = object[key].substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();

    // Make sure an array for the above character exists - if not create it
    // other wise JavaScript will spazz out and throw a hissy fit
    if (Object.prototype.toString.call(grouped[firstChar]) !== '[object Array]') {
      grouped[firstChar] = [];
    }

    // Add the current object to the grouped object
    grouped[firstChar].push(object);
  });

  // Return the grouped object
  return grouped;
}
```

Thirdly, call the grouping function we just made. The great thing about using the prototype approach is you can just call the function on the array without having to pass things around as variables.

We just tell the function to group by the "name" key:

```
var groupedCamp = camp.groupAlphabeticallyByKey('name');
```

The contents of `groupedCamp` should be the following:

```
{
  A: [
    {
      campaign_id: 2,
      name: "A_SC_TSTC_495-172"
    },
    {
      campaign_id: 2,
      name: "A_SC_TSTC_Q413_915495-172"
    }
  ],
  R: [
    {
      campaign_id: 4,
      name: "R_413_915495-172"
    },
    {
      campaign_id: 1,
      name: "RE TW 155700375"
    }
  ]
}
```

You really won't get anything more optimised than this. Give it a go and let me know how you get on.

Comment: Would upvote, if the grouping wasn't a prototype method.